# Create task from within another running task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In Python I create two async tasks:

```
tasks = [
    asyncio.create_task(task1(queue)),
    asyncio.create_task(task2(queue)),
]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Now, I have a need to create a third task "task3" **within** task1.

So I have:

```
async def task1(queue):
    # and here I need to create the "task3":
    asyncio.create_task(task3(queue))
    # and how can I schedule this?
```

So I wish to schedule task3 also, without hurting task1 and task2 (they shall stay running).

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Haven't you already done that with `asyncio.create_task(task3(queue))`?

Comment: `asyncio.create_task` schedules argument to be run and returns immediately. So, yea, you've already done it, but not, that task1 will finish almost immediately since it contains a single function call that returns immediately.

Comment: Consider all tasks LONG RUNNING!!

Comment: asyncio.create_task(task3(queue)): I wish this to return immediately and let task1 do its own long business.

Comment: @Daniel That's what it does. It submits `task3` to the event loop and continues running. Keep in mind, if there are no context switches within `task1`, `task3` will never get a chance to run.

Comment: Ah, maybe I got confusion with the 'gather' function: is it only needed to wait for both task1 and task2 to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a done callback to it, and just let the your task1 run forward. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback

A matter that could arise there, though, and that is buried in the docs: the asyncio loop avoids creating hard references (just weak) to the tasks, and when it is under heavy load, it may just "drop" tasks that are not referenced somewhere else.

So, you can have a registry, a `set` structure at module level will do, to keep track of your new tasks, and then you can use the done callback so that each task can remove itself from there:

```
task3_registry = set()
...

async def task1(queue):
    # and here I need to create the "task3":
    t3 = asyncio.create_task(task3(queue))
    task3_registry.add(t3)
    t3.add_done_callback(lambda task: task3_registry.remove(task))
    ...
...
```

Even with this, when shutting down your asyncio loop (if that happens), the asyncio loop could just cancel the un-awaited-for task3's : then you can simply use that registry again to await for the completion of all of them, before returning from your root co-routine:

```
async def main():
   tasks = [
       asyncio.create_task(task1(queue)),
       asyncio.create_task(task2(queue)),
   ]
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
   await asyncio.gather(task3_registry)
   # return
```

Further answering:

> If I have a t3_is_running = True variable in task1, can lambda in the add_done_callback change it to False?

If you need the variable inside task1 co-routine, it can be seen and changed from the callback as a closure variable. That requires writting the callback with the `def` syntax instead of lambda (it is just completely equivalent performance wise):

```
async def task1(queue):
    # and here I need to create the "task3":
    t3 = asyncio.create_task(task3(queue))
    task3_registry.add(t3)
    task3_is_running = True
    def done_callback(task):
        nonlocal task3_is_running
        task3_is_running = False
        task3_registry.remove(task)
    t3.add_done_callback(done_callback)
    
...
```

If you want to see that variable from the the code in `main` however, and not as just something the code inside task1 can see, the callback have to be able to see the "task1" task instance itself. If they are single tasks, a global (in Python really a "module level variable") is just good enough - otherwise similar registries to task3_registry have to be created.

If you don't want to have global states running around, you can just encapsulate your tasks in a class, even if you are not otherwise using object orientation: this allows one task to change the state for others by using attributes in the instance:

```
class TaskSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task3_instance = None
        self.task3_is_running = False
        self.queue = ...
        pass  # can't really be run as async - can actually be omitted
    async def async_run (self):
        # this will be executed by Python as an instance of the class 
        # when it is awaited.
        

        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(self.task1(self.queue)),
            asyncio.create_task(self.task2(self.queue)),
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        if self.task3_instance:  # or use a set if more than one task3 might be running
            await self.task3_instance 
        
    async def task1(self):
        ...
        self.task3_instance = asyncio.create_task(t3)
        self.task3_is_running = True  # not actually needed, as then one could just 
                                      # check self.task3_instance and maybe call self.task3_instance.done
        
        self.task3_instance.add_done_callback(self.task3_done_callback)
        ...
        
    async def task2(self):
        ...
    async def task3(self):
        ...
        
    def task3_done_callback(self, ctx=None):
        self.task3_instance = None
        self.task3_is_running = False
        
        
asyncio.run(TaskSet().async_run())
```

Comment: If I have a `t3_is_running = True` variable in `task1`, can `lambda` in the *add_done_callback* change it to *False*?

Comment: Yes, but then it is better not to write it as a lambda - just use the longform "def" - if the variable is _inside_ the task that is needed, because Python will need to use the "nonlocal" statement. If you want that as an attribute to task1, then it could be written as a labda.  Anyway, I am adding some example snippets.

Comment: For me, it drops an error: `ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <__main__.TaskSet object at ...>`

Comment: Sorry for that - `__await__` is used for low level implementations - it looks like there is no easy way to make the class itself `awaitable`. we have to use an async method by any other name - I will use `async_run` (editing the code above now)

Comment: `task3_done_callback` is not valid with one parameter: it needs two: `task3_done_callback(self, ctx)`. And `queue` can't be created in `__init__` if it needs to be accessible from async functions.

Comment: In case *t3* contains a big for loop with complex operations (long running), and I wish to sometimes add items to the queue with either `await self.queue.put` or `self.queue.put_nowait`, *t2* and *t1* won't read the queue until *t3* finishes its long-running for loop. But in case I drop an async sleep into for loop, it works. Can I somehow prevent this?

Comment: as for the last comment: no, that is basically how asyncio works. The only way to run concurrently, ever, is when there are `await` expressions yielding to the main loop. You will have to populate your long running code with an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` if you need other things to proceed.

Comment: as for the missing ctx parameter: thanks - I fixed that in the listing. As for the queue: feel free to instantiate it however you can, it does not need to be an attribute there. Even the organization of everything as  a class is just a sugestion, you can just use module level (global)  references directly in the functions.